# latexmk generates oddly spaced letters

Tags: spacing, characters, latexmk, letterspacing

In the following text the words `sich` and `kostenlose` have oddly spaced letters in them, specifically `i`, `c` and `e`.

[image: oddly spaced text]

How can I fix this? I am using latexmk version 4.61 and MiKTeX.

Here is my working environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{titleps}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{lastpage}

  \setlength{\headheight}{52pt}
  \setlength{\textheight}{636pt}

  \title{}
  \author{}
  \date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle
\section{Kosten eine OLTP-Anwendung mit 1000 Usern}
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing
\subsection{SQL Server 2017 Express}
Die Express-Edition eignet sich für kleine datengesteuerte Serveranwendungen mit bis 10 GB. Da 1000 User am Beispiel Webuntis wahrscheinlich weniger als diese Datenbegrenzung benötigen, würde sich diese \textbf{kostenlose} SQL Server Edition eignen.
\subsection{SQL Server 2017 Standard}
Sollte sich herausstellen, dass dieser Datenumfang nicht genügt, gibt es noch die Standard-Edition, die sich für nicht-kritische Arbeitslast eignet. Für diese gibt es zwei Lizensierungsmodelle:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{per core}: \\ Hier bezahlt pro Kern des Servers. Eine Lizenz gilt für 2 Kerne und kostet derzeit \textbf{\$3.717}.
  \item \textbf{server + CAL} (Client access licenses): \\ Hier bezahlt man für den gesamten Server (egal, wie viele Kerne dieser hat) und dann für jeden Client, der darauf zugreifen kann. Eine solche Lizenz kostet \textbf{\$931}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: First, it can't be latemk's fault, since all latexmk is to run (pdf)latex, which does all the typesetting work. Second, I am unable to reproduce your problem with either pdflatex or plain latex. I'd be tempted to blame your pdf viewer. Or is that the dvi file you are showing a clip from? In any case, just try to zoom in more and see if the problem disappears. You could also try printing it and see what happens then.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The clip is from the pdf-Output. I just tried opening it with different pdf viewers and it seems that Chromium, Google Chrome and Okular on Linux display it *with* the odd spacing, but Google Chrome on Windows and the standard pdf viewer on iOS display the letters correctly. Very strange.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Oh, and when zooming in it also seems to be displayed correctly.